# Laravel observer property not being called on update

Tags: php, laravel, observers

I am looking into observers and I found out that instead of calling an observer during the `boot()` method of the `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` laravel can call it using the property `protected $observers`.

It works perfectly fine when calling it in the boot method, but it does not work when I put it in the property.

What am I doing wrong? I could not find any other explanation in the documentation.

My eventServiceProvider:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Summary of Observers
     * @var mixed
     */
    protected $observers = [
        User::class => [UserObserver::class],
    ];

    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //User::observe(UserObserver::class);
        //Above line is commented because property $observers is used, but uncommented when property observers is commented.
    }
```

My observer:

```
class UserObserver
{

    /**
     * Handle the User "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(User $user)
    {
        $dirty = $user->getChanges();
        dump($user);
        dd($dirty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Events and observers usually work behind the scenes, so `dd` and `dump` won't show up where you think it will. `Log::info()` would be better, then you check the Laravel log file for the information.

Comment: I will sure check this out, The thing is when I use it in the boot function the DD does work, but when I called it using the property it did nothing so I just assumed it would not work.

Comment: I can't tell what's going wrong from the code you provided, it looks like everything is set up correctly. And Laravel uses the `$model::observe(...)` method behind the scenes, so there really shouldn't be any difference between the two approaches. You can check to see if the observer listeners have been registered with the command `php artisan event:list --event "eloquent.updated: App\Models\User"`. That might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @aynber the Log::info() unfortunately did not add anything to the log file.